# Leaflet - Map is not getting center aligned

Tags: jquery, html, leaflet

I am using leafletjs to show map. I am not able to fix the map to center. When i, re size the window, then the map seems fixing itself to center. I have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gFyuJ/) . This problem occurs in this specific scenario of HTML 
This is my HTML

```
    <div id="test">click</div>
    <div id ="left" style = "width:100px; height:500px; float:left; background-color:red"></div> 
    <div style ="width:100%">
       <div style ="width:80%; height:auto">
          <div id="list" style = "height:500px;background-color:black"></div>
          <div id="map" style = "height:500px;display:none"></div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Map canvas' position and size should be fixed before map created. Hide/show `<div>`s first, then create map. Change order of `createMap();` and `$("#map").show();$("#list").hide();`.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e6y5k/

Comment: i fixed it by using `map.invalidateSize();` though

Comment: It may be a solution, but avoid using it as possible as you can since `invalidateSize()` causes repaint.